# fetching multiple usernames from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comments section on a website i'd like to streamline a bit if possible so it's not as much of an impact on the database. When a user selects a post, and if it has comments associated with it, it lists the comments. when the comments list, it fetches the username from another table. I store the id for the user in the comments table, and use that id to select the record from the users table. and displays as "user" said:

lets say i have 1000 comments on a post, it will hit the users table 1000 times to grab user names. I think this is probably a bad design. i thought of a few solutions, but don't know what would be recommended in this situation.

should i just be storing the username inside the comments table?

should i store all of the usernames already called in a session array?

put all of the usernames in a file, and call from the file?

or is there another solution that i haven't thought of?

i'm kind of confused. I thought i was doing the right thing by using the IDs in the comment table, and then using it to fetch the username, but after reading about a million posts on using less impact on the database, i'm starting to question myself.

WOW, thanks for all of the useful answers. here is the table scheme, i don't know why i didn't put in in originally.

comments table for jokes:

```
id | author_id | joke_id | date_created | body
---+-----------+---------+--------------+-----
1  |     3     |    2    | 2011-06-12   | this is a comment
```

and for the users:

```
id | user_name | password | email | date_joined | visible
---+-----------+----------+-------+-------------+---------
 3 |   booboo  | password | email | todays_date |    1
```

Comment: Are you you using a `JOIN`, or doing multiple queries?

Comment: It is better if you add your tables scheme to the question.

Comment: if you have relations in your table than use **joins** no need to fire a query every time it's only one query which has all information.

Comment: @JaredFarrish when i fetch the usernames, i'm doing multiple SELECT queries

Comment: You need to use `JOIN`s to bring in data from other tables that relates to the current query whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `JOIN`s are for - so that you can run a single query and efficiently get the combined information from multiple tables. E.g.:

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.content, users.name
FROM comments
JOIN users ON comments.user = users.id
WHERE comments.id in (1,2,3)
```

would look up the 3 comments with id 1, 2, and 3, plus also get the username of each commenter, and return rows that looked like this:

```
comments.id | comments.content  | users.name
------------+-------------------+---------
1           | "First comment."  | "Poster1"
2           | "Second comment." | "Poster2"
3           | "Third comment."  | "Poster3"
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a userID field in your comments table, but need to look up the username, correct?  If so, a JOIN would be the best solution.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `comments`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `comments`.`userid`
WHERE `postid`='1'
```

To read more on joins and their endless possibilities, read up [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php)

Comment: Thanks for the link. i've used tizag.com a few times. For some reason, joins seem to be over my head. It's not that i don't understand them, they just confuse me setting up the query.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN users ON comments.posterid = users.id`

Google for LEFT JOIN for more info :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you allow the same username to be used more than once? If not, then I would use the `username` field as the PK of your `users` table and store that in the `comments`table as the FK. That'll solve your issue nicely.

If changing the PK of your `users` table is too much of an issue, then just store the username in the `comments` section since you can still use that select a single record from your `users` table.